# ¿Cómo obtener la longitud del array cuando se elimina un elemento y cada vez que se hace una petición ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

mi problema es que no puedo obtener la cantidad de elementos que tiene mi array de preguntas ya que utilizo array_shift() para extraer y eliminar siempre la primera posición, se que esta función lo hace pero al parecer cuando intento calcular la longitud con sizeof() no tiene efecto. No detecta que se a cambiado de tamaño, sin embargo si cambia de pregunta.

Solo funciona la primera vez que se ejecuta después ya no. Alguien que me ayude porfa o me recomiende alguna otra alternativa de solución. Gracias.

Mi código ajax, el cual si me funciona.

```
request.done(function(data){

            if(data.estado=="correcto"){
                alert("Exito, cantidad " + data.cantidad);
                $("#show_pregunta").html("Pregunta: </br> " + data.pregunta);


            }else{
                alert("Error");
            }
});
```

Mi código php donde capturo mis valores:

```
$array_preguntas = array();

if(isset($_GET['activar_envio']) && !empty($_GET['activar_envio'])){

            if($_GET['activar_envio']){
                //Se supone que aquí obtengo el primer elemento pero a la vez lo elimino del array, asi que el array se recorre y se disminuye en uno. 
                $pregunta = array_shift($array_preguntas);
                //Aquí intento obtener la longitud la cual no cambia cada vez que se hace la petición ajax 
                $cantidad_preguntas = sizeof($array_preguntas);

                var_dump($cantidad_preguntas);
                //Intente con esto pero igual no cambia la cantidad 
                //$cantidad_preguntas = count($array_preguntas);




                $datos["pregunta"]  = $pregunta; 
                $datos["cantidad"] = $cantidad_preguntas;
                $datos["estado"] = "correcto";
            }else{
                $datos["estado"] = "error";  
            }

  }
```

Muestro la primera pregunta del $array_preguntas por primera vez cuando aparece la pagina o se recarga:

Y aquí se actualiza la pregunta cuando termino de enviar mi petición ajax, pero no me trae la cantidad que debería ser ya que al recargar la pagina ya le quito 1 al array y cuando se realiza la petición se elimina otro. E incluso aunque no me valiera la primera eliminación o sea esta, no lo detecta en mi ajax.

```
<h5 id="show_pregunta">
   <?php
    $pregunta = array_shift($array_preguntas);
        echo "Pregunta: </br> " .  $pregunta; 
 </h5>
```

Comment: La pregunta no es clara, no se entiende bien lo que quieres... ¿Puedes decir un poco más sobre lo que hace tu código?  es que esa *ida y venida* cada vez al servidor por cada pregunta me parece una pérdida de tiempo y de recursos... ¿Cuántas preguntas son?  ¿Por qué no las traes todas de una vez en una sola petición Ajax y luego haces lo que tengas que hacer en el cliente?  Sólo pregunto, unas preguntas que no van a entrar en tu array de pregtuntas :)

Comment: Lo ise así amigo porque dentro de ese .php hago una consulta a mi BD de la tabla preguntas y son 48 así que las mando al array y con la peticion ajax las voy recogiendo una por una. Aunque no es mala idea de traer todas si fuese ese el caso cómo me traigo todas las preguntas al javascript?

Comment: Amigo voy a tratar de hacer lo sugerido ahora que lo pienso es mejor controlar todas las preguntas por el lado del cliente.

Comment: Puedes perfectamente traer todas las preguntas al cliente de una vez, por ejemplo mediante un JSON que tenga todas las preguntas y luego operar con ellas desde el cliente. Eso te evitará estar cada vez viajando al servidor, ahorrarás recursos y todo irá mucho más rápido. Luego en el cliente puedes tratar las preguntas desde Javascript, dependiendo lo que quieras hacer, que tampoco queda claro. En cuanto a traerlas desde el servidor, aquí mismo hay varias respuestas que explican cómo traer datos desde el servidor y manejarlos luego mediante Javascript.

Comment: Amigo gracias por la recomendación ya entiendo estoy en ello. :) Poco a poco estoy avanzando jejeje

Comment: Puede que sea solo mi impresión pero... No estarías pensando en extraer 1 elemento del array por lo tanto en la próxima petición ajax habría uno menos, no??

Comment: Amigo gracias por intentarlo, pero ya lo solucione hasta luego. :)

Comment: Hola @DiegosSánchez Me alegra que hayas encontrado la respuesta! Como nota, las preguntas auto respondidas son bien vistas en la comunidad, por lo que si encontraste la respuesta por ti mismo, te sugiero publicarla como respuesta y aceptarla, así si alguien mas se encuentra con este problema puede tener una orientación en la respuesta!

Comment: Ok es cierto jjeje

Answer (score 0):

A ver, si haces una petición ajax hacia tu archivo php, cada vez que hagas una petición todas tus variables vuelven estar reinicializadas, por eso a la primera petición ajax te funciona, si vuelves hacer la petición ajax, el estado anterior de esas variables se reinicializa y siempre te devolverá el mismo resultado... A menos que el `$array_preguntas` lo guardes en una variable de sesión, ya que asi el valor persiste a menos que borres la cache del navegador.

```
session_start();

$array_preguntas = array();

if(!isset($_SESSION['preguntas'])){ // SI NO EXISTE LA VARIABLE DE SESION ENTONCES
     // LA RELLENAMOS CON TU ARRAY
      $_SESSION['preguntas'] = $array_preguntas 
}

if(isset($_GET['activar_envio']) && !empty($_GET['activar_envio'])){

            if($_GET['activar_envio']){
                $pregunta = array_shift($_SESSION['preguntas']);
                $cantidad_preguntas = sizeof($_SESSION['preguntas']);

                var_dump($cantidad_preguntas);




                $datos["pregunta"]  = $pregunta; 
                $datos["cantidad"] = $cantidad_preguntas;
                $datos["estado"] = "correcto";
            }else{
                $datos["estado"] = "error";  
            }

  }
```

Comment: Amigo gracias por todo, se le agradece pero ya lo solucione segui la sugerencias para no sobrecargar el servidor me traje todas las preguntas ya lo termine. :)

Answer (score 0):

ATENCIÓN AMIGOS: la solución que tuve fue dejar al servidor ya que hacía una petición cada vez que quería mostrar una pregunta es mejor hacerlo así:

//Usted puede hacerlo con un click de un botón etc, lo tengo así porque no tengo botón más que los radios button donde al momento de seleccionar se tiene que cambiar la pregunta, pero antes debe cargar una primera pregunta, por eso uso ready, al principio.

```
var activar = true;        
var contador = 0;
var array_preguntas = new Array();

$(document).ready(function(){
   //La petición ajax,la diferencia esta en la variable data solo necesite de una variable. 
   var request = $.ajax({
            url: "cuestionario.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:{ activar_envio: activar},
            dataType:"jsonp",
            jsonp:"jsoncallback",
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false
        });
}

if(data.estado=="correcto"){
     //Extraigo todas las preguntas de mi php BD     
     array_preguntas = data.preguntas.slice();
     $("#show_pregunta").html("Id_Pregunta: " + array_preguntas[contador]);

}else{
     alert("Error");
}

Por ultimo controlas las preguntas para mostrarlas, en mi caso el radio
 $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
    //Aquí pones la condición para que al momento de que el contador supere a la longitud de array no muestre undefined y eso quiero decir que ya acabo de responder todo y ya lo mandas por de quieras.
}

  Para pasar las preguntas y después enviárselo por el lado del cliente (javascript)  el código es el mismo solo agregar esto.
 $datos["preguntas"]  = $array_preguntas;
```